# How to import packages within my Aurelia application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I have a successful app running using Aurelia, however I developed it using VSCode and the skeleton that Aurelia gives you. Now that the CLI is available I'm trying to port the application over to a VS2015/Asp.net Core project but I'm having some difficulties.

In the VSCode project, there's a bundles.js file within the build folder that Gulp uses to compile it (from what I understand). In that file, there's a "dist/aurelia" section and that's where I put all of the extra packages that I need to import and it will import the css and js files. Looks like this:

```
"dist/aurelia": {
      "includes": [
        "aurelia-framework",
        "aurelia-bootstrapper",
        "aurelia-fetch-client",
        "aurelia-router",
        "aurelia-animator-css",
        "aurelia-templating-binding",
        "aurelia-polyfills",
        "aurelia-templating-resources",
        "aurelia-templating-router",
        "aurelia-loader-default",
        "aurelia-history-browser",
        "aurelia-logging-console",
        "bootstrap",
        "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text",
        "fetch",
        "jquery",
        "rstacruz/nprogress",
        "moment",
        "systemjs/plugin-text/*.js",
        "components/jqueryui",
        "quilljs",
        "rich-text",
        "util",
        "signalr"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": false,
        "rev": false
      }
    }
```

However, when I use the command `au new --here` to create a new project within VS2015, the generated project looks a little different. I have an aurelia_project folder and within that it looks like that's where all of the building/compiling happens. In that folder, there's an aurelia.json file and that's where I need to put all of the packages (I'm using NPM btw) I've been told. When I try to import these packages, it appends .js to the file path automatically and totally leaves out CSS so it's failing to load my CSS when the page loads. Here's what the aurelia.json looks like:

```
"dependencies": [
          "aurelia-binding",
          "aurelia-bootstrapper",
          "aurelia-dependency-injection",
          "aurelia-event-aggregator",
          "aurelia-framework",
          "aurelia-history",
          "aurelia-history-browser",
          "aurelia-loader",
          "aurelia-loader-default",
          "aurelia-logging",
          "aurelia-logging-console",
          "aurelia-metadata",
          "aurelia-pal",
          "aurelia-pal-browser",
          "aurelia-path",
          "aurelia-polyfills",
          "aurelia-route-recognizer",
          "aurelia-router",
          "aurelia-task-queue",
          "aurelia-templating",
          "aurelia-templating-binding",
          {
            "name": "text",
            "path": "../wwwroot\\scripts/text"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-templating-resources",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-resources/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-templating-resources"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-templating-router",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-router/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-templating-router"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-testing",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-testing/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-testing",
            "env": "dev"
          },
          {
            "name": "jquery",
            "path": "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min"
          },
          {
            "name": "bootstrap",
            "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/",
            "main": "bootstrap"
          }
        ]
      }
```

So, I'm my VSCode project, I imported bootstrap css on the html page via a require tag. Is that still the proper way to do things? If so, how do I fix this importing issue?

**EDIT**

The answer below helped be get a bit further. Now the project builds and runs without any errors however, I can't seem to get the bootstrap css imported correctly.

Here's a snippet of my new aurelia.json file:

```
{
            "name": "aurelia-testing",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-testing/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-testing",
            "env": "dev"
          },
          "jquery",
          {
            "name": "bootstrap",
            "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js",
            "main": "bootstrap",
            "resources": [
              "../css/*.css"
            ]
          }
```

So this is adding the css file into the bootstrap package. Now, in my typescript file, I'm calling `import 'jquery'` and `import 'bootstrap'` and I don't get any css still. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens is that aurelia skeleton-esnext uses SystemJS, and Aurelia-CLI uses RequireJS (SystemJS and WebPack will be supported on CLI in a near future). SystemJS and RequireJS are module loaders, and they behave a little different. That's why you have 2 different ways to configure the modules.

This link shows how to configure a lib that has a css file:
http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/9

```
"dependencies": [
  ...
  {
    "name": "nprogress",
    "path": "../node_modules/nprogress",
    "main": "nprogress",
    "resources": [
      "nprogress.css"
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

The above code tells RequireJS to put `nprogress.css` in the bundled file. However, it doesn't tell where or when to import/require the css file, so you must import/require it in your app. Either using `<require from="nprogress/nprogress.css"></require>` in your view, or using `import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';` in your view-model.

When you were using SystemJS you didn't have to import some css files because JSPM can detect some dependencies and generate a special syntax that tells SystemJS to load CSSs files. For example, when you install `nprogress` using JSPM, it generates the following file:

```
/* */ 
"format global";
"deps ./nprogress.css!";
/* NProgress, (c) 2013, 2014 Rico Sta. Cruz - http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress
 * @license MIT */

;(function(root, factory) {
///....
```

The line "deps ./nprogress.css!"; tells SystemJS to automatically import/require `nprogress.css` when you load the module. Therefore, you don't have to import/require the css file in your view or view-model.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That helps. Now I've gotten it to compile the js and css in the aurelia.json file and it loads the page without any errors. However, I'm still having trouble requiring the css.

I'm adding the bootstrap dependency with the path of "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js" and the resources of "../css/*.css".

In my view-model I've got 'import jquery' and 'import bootstrap' and that doesn't seem to import the css. The 'import bootstrap' should import both css and js files, right?

Comment: No no no. I said that SystemJS can detect some dependencies and load them automatically (depending on module configuration). If you are using CLI (RequireJS in your case) you have to import all css files

Comment: I believe I've done that. Check the edited question. I posted some snippets of the revised aurelia.json file.

Comment: You must import css files when using aurelia-cli. For example: `<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>`

Comment: When I do that, I get an error and the page doesn't load. I get "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires Jquery"

Comment: Follow this tutorial step-by-step http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/1

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [contact-manager tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial) by Rob Eisenberg

It shows how to add Jquery, Bootstrap to aurelia.json:

```
"dependencies": [
...
"jquery",
{
"name": "bootstrap",
"path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
"main": "js/bootstrap.min",
"deps": ["jquery"],
"exports": "$",
"resources": [
  "css/bootstrap.css"
]
},
...
]
```

And how to require it in app.html:

```
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
```

I was able to successfully do the same for D3:

```
{
"name": "d3",
"path": "../node_modules/d3/build",
"main": "d3.js"
},
```

Then I was able to use it in my components .js file

```
import * as d3 from d3
```

[Edit] Just noticed tutorial link was included in above accepted answer, but keeping this as it shows the actual code for adding jquery/bootstrap, which has some elements missing in the OP examples, including after the edit.

Comment: Reproduced all steps. The error message "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" is still there. I'm in a new project created by the CLI.

Comment: @alearg Can you post your project to a temp public repo, or upload some where? Would be easier to debug/give feedback to you that way.

Also, a more in depth description on adding libraries to your project is available on the [auerlia-cli README.md] (https://github.com/aurelia/cli)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Have a look here for the reason of my problem

Comment: Can I use a similar method to this if I just want to load the bootstrap.css? (i.e. I don't need jQuery)